# Why does defined function not work?

Tags: arrays, perl, string, undef

I have a piece of code which does not work as I expect it to work. MAinly the defined function does not work.

```
@jobs = qw[job1 undef job2];
if(defined($jobs[1])) {
  print "Job 1 is defined";
}
```

I get the output

```
Job 1 is defined
```

clearly `$jobs[1]` is `undef`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using `qw`, your code is equivalent to:

```
@jobs = ("job1", "undef", "job2");
```

So `$jobs[1]` is the **string** `"undef"` which is not same as `undef` and hence the behavior.

If you want the second job to be an `undef` you can do:

```
@jobs = ("job1", undef, "job2");
```

AFAIK you cannot get this done using `qw`.

Comment: @user582452 - a data dumper (such as Data::Dumper - http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Dumper/ ) is your friend. `print Dumper(\@jobs)` would have shown you what was in your array